# Why doesn't my Storboard show?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

In my `MainPage.xaml` I have defined this storyboard. When the app first runs it works great, I can call the `Begin()` function and everything is well. But if i go to anther `.xaml` page and go back, it does not work when i call the `Begin()` function.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Maybe start begin the animation with OnLoad instead?

Comment: The animation is started by an event .Completed not the load. I've set breakpoints, it runs as it should but the animation does not show.

Comment: So the first time you load your mainpage and complete your event it fires off the animation fine, but then when you-revisit the same view then it does not?

Comment: When I revisit the same page yes. I have tried wrapping it in Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( without luck

Comment: What event is firing off the animation?

Comment: proximityDevice_DeviceArrived but I can ensure you, I've breakpointed the application. It runs the storyboard. the storyboard is animating a image opacity from 0->1, when it's done it fire off the other storyboard animating the image's opacity from 1->0. I works fine the first time around, but after visiting another xaml page and back it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say "go back" are you using NavigationService.GoBack() or are you using NavigationService.Navigate("myFirstPage.xaml")? If you're using the Navigate() method then you're doing forward navigation to a new page. If you're using back navigation then you'll be going to the same instance of the page as before.

Also note that WP7/8 doesn't always cache the page in the back stack. When memory pressure arises (e.g. from D3D usage) pages in the back stack might get GCed. You can fine tune your app's back stack navigation caching with [Page.NavigationCacheMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.page.navigationcachemode%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and [Frame.CacheSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.frame.cachesize%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: I'm not overriding OnBackKeyPress

Comment: So yeah, it just might be that the back stack has been cleared, pages GCed and the only thing that's being cached is the URL.